# Change .popover-title style individually

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to style each popover title separately, one would be for danger (red) and one for warning (orange).

`HTML`:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<button id='popovername1' style='background-color: red; color: white;'>
  Pop1
</button>

<button id='popovername2' style='background-color: orange; color: black;'>
  Pop2
</button>
```

I tried using `jQuery eq()` to do this, but it doesn't work. One of the popovers should be red and the others orange:

```
$(function() {

  $('#popovername1').popover({
    html: true,
    placement: 'right',
    container: 'body',
    title: 'Info',
    content: 'Pop1',
    trigger: 'focus'
  });

});

$(function() {

  $('#popovername2').popover({
    html: true,
    placement: 'right',
    container: 'body',
    title: 'Info',
    content: 'Pop2',
    trigger: 'focus'
  });

});

$(function() {
  $('.popover-title:eq(0)').css({'background-color':'red','color':'white'});
});
```

`CSS`:

```
.popover-title {
  background-color: orange !important;
  color: black;
}
```

`Pop1` popover should be red, but I can't make it change color. Everyone turns orange.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But now both popovers are colorless now, neither orange nor red.

Comment: `$('.popover-title:eq(0)')` this line runs when the page loads - at that point the popover-titles don't exist as they are added dynamically when you click the pop buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.popover` is provided by [bootstrap 3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#popovers), which has limited scope for per-instance customisation.

One option is to listen for the `inserted.bs.popover` event, which fires once the popup has been dynamically inserted into the DOM, and apply the styles then:

```
$("#popovername1").on("inserted.bs.popover", () => $('.popover-title').css({'background-color': 'red', 'color': 'white' }));
$("#popovername2").on("inserted.bs.popover", () => $('.popover-title').css({'background-color': 'orange', 'color': 'white' }));
```

You could also do this with classes, but note that bootstrap css is always over specified, so you need to add enough css specification.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#popovername1').popover({
    html: true,
    placement: 'right',
    container: 'body',
    title: 'Info',
    content: 'Pop1',
    trigger: 'focus'
  });

  $('#popovername2').popover({
    html: true,
    placement: 'right',
    container: 'body',
    title: 'Info',
    content: 'Pop2',
    trigger: 'focus'
  });

  $("#popovername1").on("inserted.bs.popover", () => $('.popover-title').addClass("error"));
  $("#popovername2").on("inserted.bs.popover", () => $('.popover-title').addClass("warning"));
});
```

```css
.error,
.popover-title.error {
  background-color: red;
  color: white
}

.warning,
.popover-title.warning {
  background-color: orange;
  color: white
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<button id='popovername1' class='error'>Pop1</button>

<button id='popovername2' class='warning'>Pop2</button>
```